# How to solve equations using asymptotic notations?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm stuck on whether or not the asymptotic notations (options 1-5) are correct or not. 
The big-O notation rule I got (from a YouTube video) was that for O(f(n)) is the set of all functions with smaller or same order of grown as f(n), which means that option 2 would be correct because the leading term has the same order of grown as t(n). 
The little-o notation rule I got was that for O(f(n)) is the set of all functions with smaller rate of grown than f(n), which means that option 1 is correct because the leading term n^3 is smaller than o(n^4).

How would I solve this problem for the rest (Omega, Theta, and little-Omega)? I have trouble finding the explanation or rule for those.

```
Given t(n) = 53n^3+ 32n^2+ 28, which of the following is(are) correct

1) t(n) =  o(n^4) (Correct?)
2) t(n) =  O(n^3) (Correct?)
3) t(n)  =  Ɵ(n^4) 
4) t(n)  =  Ω(n^3) (Correct?)
5) t(n)  =  ɯ(n^2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of O and o is correct.

Roughly speaking, for Omega and omega, they are sort of the opposite. They are kind of bounds from below. So the growth of t(n) must be larger [larger or equal] than that of f(n) to be in omega(f(n)) [Omega(f(n)].

Theta is the same as O and Omega at the same time.

So 4 and 5 are correct and 3 is false.

The mathematically exact definitions are more involved see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 1):

```
Given t(n) = 53n^3+ 32n^2+ 28, which of the following is(are) correct

  1)t(n) = o(n^4)
==>Correct as n^4 is bigger by Function n.

 2)t(n) =  O(n^3) (Correct?)
 ==>correct :::take large C constant

 3)t(n)  =  Ɵ(n^4) 
==>false because Omega does not satisfy here.

 4)t(n)  =  Ω(n^3)<br/>==> correct

 5)t(n)  =  ɯ(n^2)
 true as it is strictly smaller than n^3
```